# .htaccess Error : Invalid command 'AuthGroupFile'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, smarty

before this i was working on windows and my project was working proper. recently i moved to ubuntu and i am trying setup project on LAMP.

i have created host for this (windows i was running directly through localhost) and when i am running it getting `500 Internal server Error`.

when i looked in my log file i got `Invalid command 'AuthGroupFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`.

.htaccess File

```
  #php_value zend.ze1_compatibility_mode off
  AuthName "Restricted Area" 
  AuthType Basic 
  AuthUserFile /opt/lampp/htdocs/uniplex_mobile/.htpasswd 
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null 

  <Files manageurls.html>
  require valid-user
  </Files>
  <Files addurl.html>
  require valid-user
  </Files>
  <Files editurl.html>
  require valid-user
  </Files>

  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

my project is on smarty framework.

can anyone help to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/522519/htaccess-error-invalid-command-authgroupfile

Answer (score 17):

You can try this.

```
a2enmod authz_groupfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using apache 2.2, this means you're missing the mod_authz_groupfile module.

You need to look in your server config and look for the line that contains:

```
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
```

or something similar and make sure it's commented out.

Otherwise, just leave out the `AuthGroupFile` directive, it doesn't look like you're using it anyways.